# Confusion about standing wave

Tags: waves, frequency

I learned that the frequency of standing wave of string with fixed ends is $n v/2L$. However, let's think about a small particle of the string. How does that particle 'know' how long the string is and oscillate with frequency $n v/2L$?

Comment: Particles don't know anything, they can only find out that a non-resonant oscillation disappears quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The formula isn't saying that the particles **must** vibrate at frequency $nv/2L$.  It is just saying that, if a standing wave of a given type exists on the string, then the particles are oscillating at that frequency.

For example, let's say you have just the simplest ($n=1$) standing wave on the string, which is a sine wave of wavelength $2L$.  The formula $f = v/2L$ is telling you that **given that this standing wave mode is present**, the particles in the string are oscillating at this frequency.  If they weren't oscillating at this frequency, this standing wave mode wouldn't be able to exist.  So depending on which standing mode is present on the string, the frequency of the particle will be different.  In fact, you can even have a combination of different standing wave modes on the string simultaneously (e.g. $n=0$ and $n=2$), in which case the particle also has a combination of different frequencies at the same time, not just one.

It is true, though, that there is only a limited set of frequencies that a particle in the string can have, and the set of frequencies to choose from is determined by $L$ (according to the formula above).  So how does the particle 'know' it can only vibrate at these frequencies and not others?  Well, the motion of a particle is determined by what is happening in its immediate vicinity.  If the particles around it are moving in a certain way, that will influence what the first particle is doing because the neighbouring particles exert forces of tension on the first particle, thereby causing it to move in certain ways.  But what the neighbouring particles are doing is itself influenced by what *their* neighbours are doing, which are influenced by what *their* neighbours are doing, and so on.  So what is happening to the first particle is, in fact, ultimately dependent on what every other particle in the string is doing.  So that also means the motion of every particle is influenced by where the two ends of the rope are tied down - i.e. how long the string is.  In this way, the length of the string constrains how any given particle in the string vibrates.

Comment: This answer does help, but there are still some confusions. In reality, frequency cannot be 'exactly' nv/2L. There must be slight error. Why can we observe standing wave in reality? Second confusion is: In the proof of the formula of standing wave, we add  Asin(kx+wt) and its reflection wave Asin(kx-wt). Why aren't we adding the reflection wave of reflection wave and reflection of reflection of reflection... and so on?

Answer (score 0):

*How does that particle 'know' how long the string is and oscillate with frequency nv/2L?*
The particle knows nothing other than what it is told by its nearest neighbors.

The system, string fixed at both ends, can be forced to oscillate, eg by plucking the string and it will oscillate, with its many natural frequencies of oscillation which over time, will die down usually with the fundamental frequency oscillation (standing wave) lasting longest.

[This Pasco promotion video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEDd9YrgRK4) illustrates the production of a range of frequencies when a string is plucked and the prominence of one frequency as the oscillations decay with the times in the red rectangle being measured in seconds.

[image]

If the system is forced to oscillation by a driver you have a system which undergoes transient oscillations at the natural frequencies of the system and ultimately, due to the transients dying down, steady state oscillations at the frequency of the driver.
The final state amplitude depends on the frequency of the driver and the natural frequencies of the system and when there are amplitude maxima the state is called resonance which will be seen as a standing wave pattern.

Your worry about "slight error" in the frequency will means that if the driver frequency is not quite that which would produce resonance (maximum response of the system) then the amplitude will be smaller than that at the resonant frequency but large enough to "mask" all other motions other than those which look as though a standing wave has been produced.

Comment: This helps a lot thank you!